# iOS App does not resume after clicking AdMob ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I use class to show AdMob ad and it has 320x50 size view, i call only this class's view where i want to display my ad in app but when i click ad and want to return back, it go back to AdMob's class and it resizes to cover all screen (Autoresize is closed) . Does anybody has solution about it?
I use this AdMob class with small view because of my other m files are mm. file and i could not make AdMob work in mm files and its also easy to call just this class's view when i need to display ad.
I use same codes as in AdMob example in official site.

```
-(void)setAdMob{

CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                               origin:origin];


// Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
// before compiling.
self.adBanner.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
self.adBanner.center =
CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
self.adBanner.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.adBanner.frame.size.width, self.adBanner.frame.size.height);
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

```
-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
 // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. They are
 // printed to the console when the app is launched.
 nil];

return request;
```

}

```
// We've received an ad successfully.

-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);}
```

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the "black" screen?

Comment: @Injectios thanks for reply i figured out something and edited my question.

Comment: I guess when you click on "banner" ad it presents modal UIViewController, right?

Comment: @Injectios yes i think so

Comment: but, what do you expect enstead?